# New User Defined Database Type Causing Database Project Build to Fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

We have a database project that we publish to our local database.  I have introduced a new database type and along with that a sproc that depends on it.  Since the database project will not build unless the type exists, what would be the recommended course of action?

I want the database project's publish to create the type first, then build out the sproc.  This will eventually make its way to Test, Stage, and Production servers, so it's important that it works locally first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buddy of mine found it -- I created the script as a regular script instead of finding the correct Visual Studio template "Add New Item > SQL Server > Programmability > User-defined Table Type", so the build action was "none" instead of "Build" as it needed to be.